# Regex lookaround

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

When all was simple we had a regex /[^A-Za-z0-9]/
Once matched, we would substitute in underscores

```
  American Football # American_Football
  Mini Golf         # Mini_Golf
```

However, we do *not* want it to match

```
  AR/ VR
```

I thought a neg lookbehind would work but alas...Why does the neg lookbehind not go back and make sure `\/\s` does not match?

```
 [^A-Za-z0-9](?<!\/\s)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't get it. What should be the output of `something AR/ VR new`? How should `AR/VR` be handled? Does `VR/ AR` matter? What is the significance of `AR` and `VR`?

Comment: Does `American/ Football` matter?

Comment: `[^A-Za-z0-9](?<!\/\s)` matches `/` in `AR/ VR` because it is not a whitespace preceded with `/`. Does it mean you only want to match non-alnum chars between words chars? Like `/\b[^A-Za-z0-9]\b/`? See https://regex101.com/r/rXgNAB/1. Or, maybe you want to only match between alnum chars, `/(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\W(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/`? See https://regex101.com/r/rXgNAB/2.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you, that makes perfect sense to me and my teammate. It was the second, but we grok the difference. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^A-Za-z0-9](?<!\/\s)` matches `/` in `AR/ VR` because it is not a whitespace preceded with `/`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qtAvql/1/debugger):

[image]

You seem to want to only match an non-alphanumeric character between alphanumeric characters:

```
/(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])\W(?=[A-Za-z0-9])/
```

See [this regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/rXgNAB/2).

**Details**

- `(?<=[A-Za-z0-9])` - right before, there must be an alphanumeric char
- `\W`  - a non-word char (non-alpha, non-underscore) char
- `(?=[A-Za-z0-9])` - right after, there must be  an alphanumeric  char.